# Geometric probability independence

Tags: probability, geometric-probability

I have a basic question about the independence of two events.

Let $x$ be some fixed point in the interior of some set (say it's a convex bounded set $C$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ or something). Choose $a, b, y$ uniformly at random and independently from the interior of $C$. Are the events that $||x - a|| < ||x - b||$ and $||y - a|| < ||y-b||$ independent? That is, is it true that $$\Pr(||x-a|| < ||x-b||\text{ and } ||y-a|| < ||y-b||) \\ = \Pr(||x-a|| < ||x-b||)\cdot\Pr(||y-a|| < ||y-b||) = 1/2?$$ I would really think so, but I'm not sure how to rigorously show this. Maybe it's enough to say that $||x-a||, ||y-a||$ are independent random variables?

What if now $a, b$ are chosen uniformly at random from some subset $C'\subset C$ (again, some "nice" subset), and $y$ is as before chosen uniformly at random from $C$. Are the events independent?

Comment: The random variables $||x-a||, ||x-b||, ||y-a||, ||y-b||$ are obviously not independent since for example $||x-a||$ and $||x-b||$ are not.

Comment: Edited. Wouldn't ||x-a|| and ||y-a|| be independent?

Comment: Well I guess they are not. If you know where $x$ is and know what $||x-a||$ is, I gues that tells you something about $||y-a||$? But intuition seems to strongly suggest that the probability I wrote should be 1/2, no?

Comment: have you tried the case of a circle

Comment: Well that seems like it would be messy, and I want to try to find an argument that doesn't really rely on any properties of the set itself.

Comment: For the first question, here's perhaps an easy argument. Clearly Pr(|x-a| < |x-b|) = 1/2. Also, Pr(|x-a| < |x-b| | |y-a| < |y-b|) = 1/2, since knowing that |y-a| < |y-b| doesn't say anything about the distances to x, as y is uniformly random. But something feels a bit off, since certainly Pr(|y-a| < |y-b|) = 1/2, which then by Bayes law means that Pr(|y-a| < |y-b| | |x-a| < |x-b|) = 1/2, and that seems a bit unintuitive.

Comment: Well, I'm not even convinced by the fact that $\Pr(||x-a|| < ||x-b||) = 1/2$, this probability should depend on $a$ and $b$. You can imagine (convex) shapes in the plane with one point $a$ in a very narrow spot so that $||x-a|| < ||x-b||$ for many $b$ most (in the sense of Lebesgue measure) of the time.

Comment: @A.Bailleul Sure, but I'm choosing a and b randomly as well. So it's just a matter of which label 'a' or 'b' gets used. So that probably definitely should be 1/2, no? Your bad examples are for specific fixed a's, but I'm looking at probability over all a and b.